# Weird typedef declaration

Tags: c

I see a *typedef* declaration in the */usr/include/png.h* file:

```
typedef void (PNGAPI *png_error_ptr) PNGARG((png_structp, png_const_charp));
```

I can't understand this declaration.

Is this a function pointer return function pointer?

Comment: Following [the clockwise/spiral rule](https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), `png_error_ptr` is a pointer to a function that takes two arguments (of type `png_structp` and `png_const_charp`) and returns nothing.

Comment: [See `cdecl.org`...](https://cdecl.org/?q=void+%28*png_error_ptr%29%28png_structp%2C+png_const_charp%29%3B)

Comment: @AKX Which as usual isn't helpful, since you didn't even paste the OP's code.

Comment: What is `PNGARG`, a macro?

Comment: @Lundin Um, I did, just peeling off the libpng specific bits.

Comment: If PNGAPI and PNGARG do the expected thing, it is a pointer to a function returning void. ("Expected thing": just remove the macros and redundant parentheses).

Comment: @Lundin Well, unless you're using a text-based browser, I'm quite certain it's trash you're using right now.

Comment: @AKX "The code is used" isn't a quality metric.

Answer (score 3):

This is a function pointer, alias declaration. Function pointer typedefs (and type casts) in C use the following syntax: `return_type (optional_calling_convention* identifier)(args)`.

So in this case, *png_error_ptr* is becoming an alias for a pointer to a function with PNGAPI calling convention that returns `void` and takes in `PNGARG((png_structp, png_const_charp))` parameters.

[`PNGARG` is a function-type macro defined as `#define PNGARG (x) x`](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/e519af8b49f52c4ac400f50f23b48ebe36a5f4df/pngconf.h#L89-L95), and [`png_structp`](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/e519af8b49f52c4ac400f50f23b48ebe36a5f4df/png.h#L441) and [`png_const_charp`](https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/e519af8b49f52c4ac400f50f23b48ebe36a5f4df/pngconf.h#L590) are types, this expands to `typedef void (PNGAPI *png_error_ptr) (png_struct *, const char *)`, which you might more easily understand as a pointer to a function that might look like: `void PNGAPI func(png_struct *arg1, const char *arg2)`.

Look [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/function-pointers/) for a more detailed explanation focused on people with no experience

Answer (score 3):

This is used in `libpng`. First you should resolve the macros:

`PNGAPI` is a placeholder for `__cdecl` or `__stdcall`, i.e. the calling convention.

`PNGARG` is a solution to cope with very old compilers, which don't have prototypes. In sane compilers it's just the argument.

So we are left with:

```
typedef void (*png_error_ptr)(png_structp, png_const_charp);
```

You start reading from left to right and you get `typedef`, so we are defining a new type. Then you get `void`, so we are looking at a definition of something  `void`, what can it be? A `void` pointer or a function which returns nothing. Let's keep going.

Next we have `(*png_error_ptr)`. This is a definition of `png_error_ptr` which is a pointer. This *could* be the definition of the new type `png_error_ptr` an alias for `void` pointer, but we have something more. We have an open parenthesis on the right, so `png_error_ptr` is an alias for a pointer to a function which returns `void`. This is consistent with the comment before:

```
/* These are the function types for the I/O functions and for the functions
 * that allow the user to override the default I/O functions with his or her
 * own.  The png_error_ptr type should match that of user-supplied warning
 * and error functions, while the png_rw_ptr type should match that of the
 * user read/write data functions.
 */
```

Can we say something more about the type of the arguments this function expects? Well, we have that:

```
typedef PNG_CONST char  FAR * png_const_charp;
typedef png_struct FAR * png_structp;
```

More ugly macros. But these are for very strange/old compilers. Usually you will have:

```
#define PNG_CONST const
#define FAR
```

so

```
typedef const char * png_const_charp;
typedef png_struct * png_structp;
```

All considered, you can assume:

```
typedef void (*png_error_ptr)(png_struct *, const char *);
```

If you want some reasonable names for the parameters, you can look at the file `pngerror.c` which provides (authors' words) "stub functions for i/o and memory allocation":

```
typedef void (*png_error_ptr)(png_struct *png_ptr, const char *error_message);
```

Basically, this is the type of function you can provide during initialization with `png_set_error_fn()`. This sets `png_ptr->error_fn` to your function pointer.

A custom error function should be something like:

```
void my_custom_error_function(png_struct *png_ptr, const char *error_message);
```

All this work is required to support old compilers, especially those coming from the DOS days, with weird memory models.